# Nginx 403 error, when nginx.conf set to serve from /websites

Tags: permissions, users, nginx

I created a `websites` folder into the `/` directory, and gave it full permission with `sudo chmod -R 777 /websites/`.

After that, I made a change in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` to point to the `websites` directory:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /websites;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }


    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /websites/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

But I am having an `403 Forbidden`, when I tried to browse to public ip of the server.

Why is it happening? How can I solve it?

I have this in the nginx error.log:

```
2017/08/27 20:41:03 [error] 3849#3849: *37 "/websites/index.html" is
forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: **.**.130.159, server:
localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "**.**.**.120"
```

Comment: What do you have in logs in `/var/log/nginx`? Do you have an index page, such as `/websites/index.html`? What system/distribution are you using?

Comment: Possibly wrong permissions on the file/folder, or/and SELinux policy not permitting access. If you have SELinux enabled you should check audit logs (tools such as [`audit2why`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/audit2why) might be helpful).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error log very clearly says:

- Your nginx would try to read `/websites/index.html`, but it can't
- This is why it gives 403 error, not because of its configuration.

It is because of the `13: Permission denied`. It is a system error. Thus, your nginx is configured well, it tries to read that file, but it can't.

The next question is, why it can't. First, you should check, what it does. Sudo to the user, on which nginx is running (it is probably www-data, so the command is: `sudo -u www-data /bin/bash`), and try to read that file for yourself (`cat /websites/index.html`).

The next step depends on, what is the result.

@sebasth has right in his comment:

> Possibly wrong permissions on the file/folder, or/and SELinux policy
>   not permitting access. If you have SELinux enabled you should check
>   audit logs (tools such as [`audit2why`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/audit2why) might be helpful).

I think the two most probable outcomes:

1. Something wasn't set up correctly with the permissions, despite that your `chmod` command looks okay
2. There is some SELinux thingy making your life nicer.

Comment: WOW Thank you very much man!! I just test it if it will work, and i run `setenforce permissive` - and it works!! Tanks again! i take the information from here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-selinux-on-centos-7-part-1-basic-concepts

Answer (score -3):

```
chmod 777 /var/www/your_site
```

solved the issue

Comment: besides the typo, this is generally not good advice (see the accepted answer)